# Fedex Address Validation Authentication Failed

Tags: postman, fedex

I'm trying to hit Fedex address validation api from postman using production credentials but getting authentication failed error in the response ..
There is no information related to production credentials in fedex api documentation.

I'm using the production EndPoint https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services

Here is the request body

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <v4:AddressValidationRequest>
 <v4:WebAuthenticationDetail>
 <v4:ParentCredential>
 <v4:Key>PRODUCTION KEY</v4:Key>
 <v4:Password>PRODUCTION PASSWORD</v4:Password>
 </v4:ParentCredential>
 <v4:UserCredential>
 <v4:Key>PRODUCTION KEY</v4:Key>
 <v4:Password>PRODUCTION PASSWORD</v4:Password>
 </v4:UserCredential>
 </v4:WebAuthenticationDetail>
 <v4:ClientDetail>
 <v4:AccountNumber>PRODUCTION ACCOUNT</v4:AccountNumber>
 <v4:MeterNumber>PRODUCTION METER</v4:MeterNumber>
 <v4:Localization>
 <v4:LanguageCode>EN</v4:LanguageCode>
 <v4:LocaleCode>EN</v4:LocaleCode>
 </v4:Localization>
 </v4:ClientDetail>
 <v4:TransactionDetail>
<v4:CustomerTransactionId>AddressValidationRequest_v54534</v4:CustomerTransactionId>
 <v4:Localization>
 <v4:LanguageCode>EN</v4:LanguageCode>
 <v4:LocaleCode>EN</v4:LocaleCode>
 </v4:Localization>
 </v4:TransactionDetail>
 <v4:Version>
 <v4:ServiceId>aval</v4:ServiceId>
 <v4:Major>4</v4:Major>
 <v4:Intermediate>0</v4:Intermediate>
 <v4:Minor>0</v4:Minor>
 </v4:Version>
 <v4:AddressesToValidate>
 <v4:ClientReferenceId>Shelby Drive</v4:ClientReferenceId>
 <v4:Address>
 <v4:StreetLines>1155 15th Street NW Suite 720 </v4:StreetLines>
 <v4:City>Washington</v4:City>
 <v4:StateOrProvinceCode>DC</v4:StateOrProvinceCode>
 <v4:PostalCode>20005</v4:PostalCode>
 <v4:UrbanizationCode>CO</v4:UrbanizationCode>
 <v4:CountryCode>US</v4:CountryCode>
 <v4:Residential>0</v4:Residential>
 </v4:Address>
 </v4:AddressesToValidate>
 </v4:AddressValidationRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the response what m getting

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <v4:AddressValidationReply xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
            <v4:HighestSeverity xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">ERROR</v4:HighestSeverity>
            <v4:Notifications xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
                <v4:Severity xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">ERROR</v4:Severity>
                <v4:Source xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">prof</v4:Source>
                <v4:Code xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">1000</v4:Code>
                <v4:Message xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">Authentication Failed</v4:Message>
            </v4:Notifications>
            <v4:TransactionDetail xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
                <v4:CustomerTransactionId xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">AddressValidationRequest_v54534</v4:CustomerTransactionId>
                <v4:Localization xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
                    <v4:LanguageCode xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">EN</v4:LanguageCode>
                    <v4:LocaleCode xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">EN</v4:LocaleCode>
                </v4:Localization>
            </v4:TransactionDetail>
            <v4:Version xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
                <v4:ServiceId xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">aval</v4:ServiceId>
                <v4:Major xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">4</v4:Major>
                <v4:Intermediate xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">0</v4:Intermediate>
                <v4:Minor xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">0</v4:Minor>
            </v4:Version>
        </v4:AddressValidationReply>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

please help :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<v4:Message xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">Authentication Failed</v4:Message>
```

Check you key, password, accountnumber, meternumber